# JQuery redireccionar a @RequestMapping(value = "...") Spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

como se puede hacer para que JQuery pueda redireccionar a un **"método de una clase controlador"** de `Spring`, me explico de la siguiente manera, tengo una página `JSP` que lo invoco desde un **"controlador"** supongamos que la **URL** es así: `http://localhost:8080/Parametros/controladorVista/Bienvenido.htm`, donde:

- `Parametros`, es el nombre de mi proyecto Spring MVC
- `controladorVista`, es una **clase controller** de `Spring` que llama al archivo `jsp` Bienvenido.

Entonces necesito que JQuery me redireccione a otra vista pero que se encuentra en otro **controlador** por medio de un `button` a la siguiente **URL**: `http://localhost:8080/Parametros/controladorPersona/registrarPersona.htm`, intente lo siguiente con JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnModificar").click(function(){
        var url = "controladorPersona/registrarPersona.htm";
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    });
});
```

Pero el resultado fue: `http://localhost:8080/Parametros/controladorVista/controladorPersona/registrarPersona.htm` y yo esperaba que saliera: `http://localhost:8080/Parametros/controladorPersona/registrarPersona.htm`, por lo que está mal porque me toma `/controladorVista` y eso hace que no se muestre mi página `JSP` porque esa ruta no existe para mi. No se si me dejo entender.
**Entonces hay una forma de solucionar esto.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entiendo bien el problema es que te envía a una dirección errónea por que se agrega un segmento de la url del controlador actual (`controladorVista`) a la url a la que quieres acceder, creo que puedes resolverlo muy simple agregando `../` al la url para que retroceda del controlador actual al nuevo controlador:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnModificar").click(function(){
        var url = "../controladorPersona/registrarPersona.htm";
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    });
});
```

No se si esto resuelve el problema.

Comment: Gracias the-breaker esto funciona muy bien, podrías un favor pasarme un `link` donde pueda descargar `ajax` yo he descargado desde la página oficial el `JQuery 3.4.1` que menciona que tiene`ajax`  pero su funcionalidad con `ajax` no corre en mi proyecto, o no se si es mejor utilizarlo desde **"Maven"** pero tampoco se como llamarlo a mi proyecto. De todos modos gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @DanielR.Anccasi, en teoría debería funcionar de la misma forma, supongo que en lugar de descargarlo puedes importarlo desde cdn, por mi parte uso la versión 3.3.1 y veo el ajax funcionar sin problemas, prueba con este cdn : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es entender cómo funciona las URL en una página HTML:

Supongamos que cargamos una página con la URL

```
https://miURL.demo/miAplicacion/miPagina
```

Dentro de esta página quieres cargar imágenes, ficheros CSS y Javascript, así como tener enlaces a otras páginas de tu aplicación, así que tenemos los siguientes elementos:

```
<img src="estaticos/magen.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/estilos/estilo.css" >
```

¿Cómo se interpretan estas direcciones?

La URL de la imagen no empieza por `http://...` ni por `/`, así que se considera una URL **relativa**: se tomará la URL de la página actual como referencia, con lo que la URL completa será

```
 https://miURL.demo/miAplicacion/estaticos/imagen.png
```

La URL del fichero de estilos comienza por `/`, con lo que se considera una `dirección absoluta dentro del dominio actual`: se tomará el dominio de la página cargada **como base** y se añadirá la URL del recurso:

```
 https://miURL.demo/estilos/estilo.css
```

También puedes jugar definiendo cuál debe ser la base, añadiendo la etiqueta

```
<base href="https://miURL.demo/miAplicacion/">
```