# Error 404 Método POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un login, valido los datos en un archivo que esta dentro de una carpeta llamada **js**, al ser estos correctos, envío los datos a un archivo **php** que está en una carpeta anterior a través del método de **jquery** llamado **post**, pero al enviar los datos al archivo **php** me manda un error:

> error 404, diciendo que el archivo no existe.

Quisiera saber, ¿de qué manera debo poner la ruta en el metodo **post**?.

Adjunto dejo mi código y capturas:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".requerido").remove();
        var usuario = $("#usuario");
        var contrasena = $("#contrasena");
        var estado = true;
        if (usuario.val() == "") {
            usuario.before("<span class='requerido'>* Campo requerido</span>");
            estado = false;
        }
        if (contrasena.val() == "") {
            contrasena.before("<span class='requerido'>* Campo requerido</span>");
            estado = false;
        }

        if (estado) {
            $.post("../validar.php", $(this).serialize(), function(r) {
                if (r == "correcto") {
                    window.location("../home.php");
                } else {
                    alert("usuario o contraseña incorrecto");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288871/jquery-redireccionar-a-requestmappingvalue-spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error `404` ocurre cuando el archivo no existe en la ruta indicada (*puede que exista, pero en otro lado/ruta*).

En tu caso, viendo la estructura del proyecto, la solución seria sacar `../`, y dejar tu código así:

```
        $.post("validar.php", $(this).serialize(), function(r) {
            if (r == "correcto") {
                window.location("home.php");
            } else {
                alert("usuario o contraseña incorrecto");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sale lo mismo, te explico, el archivo javascript con el que estoy validando los datos se llama validar.js y este se encuentra dentro de una carpeta llamada js ("localhost/tienda/js/validar.js"). Pero mi archivo en php que tambien se llama validar.php se encuentra en una ruta anterior a la del archivo validar.js ("localhost/tienda/validar.php")

Comment: @StevenCamargo, es raro, no debería dar el mismo error, voy a ver si actualizo mi respuesta. Por otro lado, no importa donde se encuentre el archivo `JS`, sino la ruta actual del navegador.

Comment: @StevenCamargo no importa donde esté ubicado el .js, importa donde se está ejecutando.

Comment: @Marcos, si también se me hizo muy raro, incluso intente abrir una ventana incógnito pensando que el problema era por la caché pero me sale lo mismo.

Comment: si, mira https://imgur.com/oootSLn

Comment: @StevenCamargo, si te fijas, la ruta no cambio, ¿estas seguro de que cambiaste el `JS`, guardaste y borraste cache?

Comment: Efectivamente eso era lo que me faltaba, eliminar caché, por mas que recargaba la pagina y la abriera en una ventana incógnito, me seguía apareciendo lo mismo. Ahora si me sale lo que debería salir. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Depende de la ruta donde estás, puedes usar la ruta completa o la ruta relativa.
Te recomiendo que leas este [post](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/xhtml/capitulo-4/enlaces-relativos-y-absolutos).

> URL absoluta: http://www.ejemplo.com/ruta1/ruta2/pagina2.html
>
> URL relativa: /ruta1/ruta2/pagina2.html

En tu caso si el archivo está en la misma carpeta no ocupas utilizar los **../**

Esto solo se usa en caso de que estés navegando hacia atrás o intentes acceder a una carpeta fuera de la ubicación actual.

```
$.post("validar.php",
```

Otra manera en la que utilizo en ocasiones enlace a otras páginas es crear una variable para todas las páginas donde obtengamos la ruta completa de la página. Y así podremos estar utilizando esta URL para nuestros fines.

**Ejemplo en código para PHP**

```
<?php 
// Para mostrar el URL de la página actual 
  
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 
                "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
  
echo $link; 
?>
```

Teniendo el enlace a la página principal podemos crear una variable global en javascript y utilizarla después.

```
var mainUrl = '<?php $link ?>';
```

Y de esta manera podemos utilizar la URL completa.

```
$.post(mainUrl + "validar.php",
```

Comment: Mi problema es que no se encuentra en la misma carpeta, se encuentra en una ruta anterior por eso pongo: "../" , pero gracias por la informacion.